# Charge Density for a Rod

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dirac-delta-distributions

In Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics*, there's a line charge distribution on a rod of length *2b*. Jackson gives the charge density in Eq. (3.132) by

$$\rho\left(\mathbf{x}\right)=\frac{Q}{2 b} \frac{1}{2 \pi r^{2}}\left[\delta\left(\cos \theta-1\right)+\delta\left(\cos \theta+1\right)\right].$$

I understand that the integral of this expression will yield $Q$ as desired. My question is what if, instead of including the $1/r^2$ term, we just divide by a factor of $1/2 (2b)^3$,

$$\rho'\left(\mathbf{x}\right)=\frac{Q}{2 b} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{2}{(2b)^3} \left[\delta\left(\cos \theta-1\right)+\delta\left(\cos \theta+1\right)\right]?$$

This would still yield $Q$, but the expression for the charge density does not depend on $r$. Is this wrong? If yes then why?

Comment: In this expression, how are (b,δ, and θ) defined?

Comment: $b$ is half the length of the rod, $\theta$ is the usual elevation angle in spherical coordinates and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution.

Answer (score 1):

First, the $\rho'(\vec r)$ is not correct. I change it to the following $\rho_2$ in Eq.(2), for $r<b$ by the step function $\Theta(b-r)$.

The equestion is what is the different between the following two forms of charge density?
$$\tag{1}
\rho_1\left(\mathbf{x}\right)=\frac{Q}{2 b} \frac{1}{2 \pi r^{2}}\left[\delta\left(\cos \theta-1\right)+\delta\left(\cos \theta+1\right)\right] \,\Theta(b-r).
$$

$$\tag{2}
\rho_2\left(\mathbf{x}\right)=\frac{3Q}{2 b^3} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \left[\delta\left(\cos \theta-1\right)+\delta\left(\cos \theta+1\right)\right]\Theta(b-r).
$$

We may examine the amounts of linear charge density, $\lambda_1(r)$ and $\lambda_2(r)$, for the spherical shell between  $r$ and $r+\Delta r$:

\begin{align}
\lambda_1(r) =&\, \frac{\Delta Q_1}{\Delta r}\\
  = &\, \frac{Q}{2 b} \int_0^\pi r^2 \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \frac{1}{2 \pi r^{2}}\left\{\delta\left(\cos \theta-1\right)+\delta\left(\cos \theta+1\right)\right\}\,\Theta(b-r)\\
=&\, \frac{Q}{b}\,\Theta(b-r) \tag{3}
\end{align}

Then for $\rho_2$:
\begin{align}
\lambda_2(r) = &\, \frac{\Delta Q_2}{\Delta r} \\
 = &\, \frac{3Q}{2 b^3} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi r^2 \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \left[\delta\left(\cos \theta-1\right)+\delta\left(\cos \theta+1\right)\right]\,\Theta(b-r)\\
=&\, \frac{3Q}{b} \frac{r^2}{b^2} \,\Theta(b-r) \tag{4}
\end{align}

We see that the amounts of charge within the shell between $r$ $\to$ $r+\Delta r$ are quite different. The Eq.(3) shows that $\lambda_1$ is a constant, $\frac{Q}{b}$, just like what we expected. But the Eq. (4), the amount of charge within the shell is proportional to $r^2$, which does not match the proposal of the problem.

Comment: I think your $\Theta(b-r)$ should be $\Theta(2b-r)$. On another note, in Eq $(3)$ you simply integrated $\rho_1$, where did you divide by $\Delta r$?

Comment: (1) Why $\Theta(2b-r)$? Is your sphere of radius $2b$? (2) Because I did not integral the $r$ direciton. Simply to emphasize that this quantity is line charge density.

Comment: It is spherical coordinate, not cylindrical coordinate.

Comment: Nevermind you’re right, I forgot the $\delta(\cos \theta \pm 1)$ part.

Comment: Anyway I honestly don’t understand the transition from the first to the second line in the $\lambda_1$ equation, I will take a look at it again.